# What are the references to the original Tron in Legacy?

Tags: reference, tron-legacy

In [*Tron:Legacy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104001/) (2010), there are a few Easter egg/references to the original [*Tron*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084827/) (1982). A couple that I can think of off the top of my head are:

- Sam saying "Now that's a big door!" when breaking into Encom at the beginning (Direct quote from Kevin in Tron)
- Dumont on the front of the container making up part of Sam's residence.

I am not looking for references to other movies such as [this list on IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104001/movieconnections/?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn), which is references to other movies, but solely references to the original Tron film.

Answer (score 8):

Kotaku published [a list](https://kotaku.com/5715324/15-easter-eggs-to-watch-out-for-in-tron-legacy) of 10 nods to the original Tron from Tron Legacy. 
Here's the list:

1. Cillian Murphy has an uncredited appearance as Ed Dillinger Jr, the son of Ed Dillinger from the original Tron
2. In 1989, Kevin Flynn hums the theme from the original Tron
3. Right in the beginning, when Alan meets Sam in his container-house apartment, Sam changes his shirt. This is very similar to the scene in the first film when Alan comes to the arcade, and Flynn goes upstairs to change his shirt.
4. Flynn's Arcade is on Mead Street, which a reference to influential Tron designer Syd Mead
5. At one point, you can see a "Dumont Shipping" sign at Sam's apartment. This is a shout out to Dumont, the tower guardian from the original film.
6. When Rinzler and Sam fight in the arena, Rinzler stops attacking Sam as soon as he's wounded. Rinzler used to be Tron, and this is a throwback to his original programming "to fight for the users" (a line he says towards the end of the film).
7. Rinzler's armor is reminiscent of Tron's from the first film.
8. There's a quick shot of a tank from the first Tron.
9. You can see a model of Flynn's Bit on his mantel.
10. Castor's End of Line Club is a tribute to the MCP's oft-repeated catchphrase ("end of line") from Tron.

Comment: In keeping with the general SE model, could you summarize them here as well? That way the information stays if the link ever dies.

Comment: Better, but you say "15 nods" and there are 10 in the list?